# IF statement based on dropdown result in google sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm working with google sheet and seeking some help.

Below is the situation and expected outcome.

- there is Income column, Payment column, Currency column, Balance column

- Income and payment is where numbers are put
- USD, JPY, THB, SGD in dropdown for currency
- wrote below to detect which currency is selected
  =IF(H7="THB",G7*, IF(H7="USD",G7*, IF(H7 = "JPY",G7)))
  (above calculation is not done in any of the 4 columns mentioned above)
- Balance column is using below calculation
  =IF(AND(F7="",G7=""),"",I6+F7-G7)

1: Input number of income / payment
2: Currency selected
3: calculate the currency rate
4: reflect the result in THB and perform the existing calculation on balance column

Could anyone please teach me how to do this.

Essentially, I would like to use the result of calculation performed based of pulldown result to perform another calculation.

In other words, in php or any language, I want to assign the calculation result to a valuable then use that valuable in different argument.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your balance column you could do what you want by joining the 2 formulas you have above or by using a helper column. The only thing I do not see in your formulas is the currency rates that you want to assign to each currency. Where are you getting the rates from?

So in a combined formula you would place the following formula:

```
=IF(H7="THB",I6+F7-G7, IF(H7="USD",(I6+F7-G7)*usdrate, IF(H7 = "JPY",(I6+F7-G7)*jpyrate)))
```

You just need to change usdrate and jpyrate with the actual exchange rates for those currencies.

Hope it helps.